# Converting <select> options into arrays for jQuery in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a  tag with something like this

```
<select>
      <% for (int i=0; i < listCity.Count; i++) { %>
      <% var city = listaCity[i]; %>
      <option><%= city.Name + ", " + city.State.Name + ", " + city.State.Country.Name %></option>
      <%} %>
</select>
```

It creates more than 4 hundred options, and I want to add the possibility of writing in a textbox maybe the State and show only the cities inside that state.

I found a solution using jQuery:

```
<script>
     $(function () {
         var availableTags = [
           "Tags",
           "Go",
           "Here"
         ];
         $("#tags").autocomplete({
             source: availableTags
         });
     });
</script>
```

Then I print them with:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>
```

I want to switch the "availableTags" elements with the  from my dropdown list but I don't know how to call them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get all options like this:

```
var availableTags = $("select option").map(function () {

    return $(this).val();

})

console.log(availableTags);
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/25Q63/)

if you need text between the option tag then:

```
var availableTags = $("select option").map(function () {

        return $(this).text();

    })
```

your code will become like:

```
$(function () {
         var availableTags = $("select option").map(function () {

        return $(this).val();

    });
         $("#tags").autocomplete({
             source: availableTags
         });
     });
```